# OpenRefine overwrites unique ID from database if rows are the same

Tags: export, uniqueidentifier, openrefine, grel

I have uploaded a dataset in openrefine from my postgresql db. In my table I have a primary key "id".

I then go about and clean my imported table in open refine doing the following two things:

1) cluster and merge several columns which contains bits of an address ("address_line_1", "address_line_2", "address_country" etc.) so that I can merge entries like `"london" "lodon" "londres"` into `london` etc...

2) Add a column `address_full` based on `address_line_1` and there concatenate other columns with the following GREL:

```
if(isBlank(cells["address_line_1_normalised"].value), " ", 
cells["address_line_1_normalised"].value)  
+ ' ' 
+ if(isBlank(cells["address_line_2_normalised"].value), " ", 
cells["address_line_2_normalised"].value)
+ ' '
+ if(isBlank(cells["address_town_normalised"].value), " ", 
cells["address_town_normalised"].value)
+ ' '
+ if(isBlank(cells["address_county_normalised"].value), " ", 
cells["address_county_normalised"].value)
+ ' '
+ if (isBlank(cells["address_postcode"].value), " ", 
cells["address_postcode"].value)
+ ' '
+ if(isBlank(cells["address_country_normalised"].value), " ", 
cells["address_country_normalised"].value)
```

3) Cluster and merge `full_address` so to standardise the addresses.

And here I would be happy with it, and want to upload again in postgres, however at the moment of the extraction I realise **that some id numbers are the same which should be impossible**, after careful enquiry I think some rows have been crushed by others.

--DETAILS--

1) I am sure I have unique IDs in the pg table. 
2) the query to get data from the pg to openrefine is:
`select * from schema_name.table_name;`
3) The output of the csv after I edited in open refine would start with the id series like this.

```
1
2
3
...
-> from row 265 it would go like this 
265 (same record 265)
265 (same record 265)
266 (same record 266)
266 (same record 266)
266 (same record 266)
267 (same record 267)
267 (same record 267)
267 (same record 267)
...
-> up until row number 2456 (whose id is 1245) and from here starts again the unique increment of the id column:
1245
1246
....
-> up until 4000 something - where it has a jump of several thousands. 
6234
```

I suppose that openrefine just overwrote all the missing records and clamped all ids of duplicate rows with the id of the first one of the list.

Does anyone who knows the workings of openrefine knows how to invert this?

Comment: Could you show the schema of your table and the query you are using to retrieve the data in OpenRefine?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it sounds - the bug was with importing data into OR from postgresql. I re imported the data using a csv and then set up a facet for duplicates in the UID column - and found out that when the project was created from pg half of the records were overwritten by other records, while using a csv, no record was overwritten.

Conclusion: using the connection to a db to create a project in OR is buggy, don't use it.